# Get SharedPreferences inside an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-broadcast

My problem is that I need information from my `shared Preferences` in an `intent`.
Everytime the intent that a Wireless network is present is send I want to check if auto uploading in my app is selected and in case it is trigger the action.

Unfortunately I can not get the `shared preferences` in this `context`, since `getApplicationContext` and `getSharedPreferences` can not be resolved.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

import static online.simpledesign.bikelog.Startup.mypreference;


    public class WifiUploader extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                if (info != null && info.isConnected()) {
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(mypreference, 0);
                    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    if (sharedpreferences.contains("autoupload")) {
                        if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean("autoupload",false)){
                            // Upload things.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am grateful for any hint.

Comment: `inside an intent` you mean inside `onReceive` method, right?

Comment: `getApplicationContext and getSharedPreferences can not be resolved` that is because each method in Java belongs to some class. If you don't call directly the class, then it is called from `this` class. And in your case `BroadcastReceiver `, which is `this`, does not have those methods.

Comment: why you are not using onReceive method context it give you context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(mypreference, 0);
```

Use this

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(mypreference, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use context instead of getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

To get proper context for SharedPreferences use `context.getApplicationContext()` inside `onReceive()`